# Weird responsive/sticky footer issues

Tags: html, css

My footer is having some odd issues when the screen resolution gets to a certain point - it responds and works with the screen size, but only the upper half of the footer has a background. I have bottom set to 0; and position set to absolute but it just isn't looking good. Any help would be appreciated.

Link to webpage (be sure to play with the responsiveness to see what I'm talking about): http://cardspoiler.com/Cardspoiler/MSoG/Navbar/Mage.html

HTML: https://github.com/Bonteqq/Cardspoiler/blob/gh-pages/Cardspoiler/MSoG/Navbar/Mage.html

CSS: https://github.com/Bonteqq/Cardspoiler/blob/gh-pages/Cardspoiler/Cardspoiler.css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue I am seeing is in the `.left` and `.right` classes. You have a `transform: translateY(25%);` attribute on them which is pushing them down past their natural positions. If you want your footer to sit at the bottom of the page and have the same look they do now change your CSS like so:

```
footer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(128,128,128,.3);
    text-align: center;
    border-top: 1px solid #232526;
}

.left, .right {
    display: inline-block;
    list-style-type: none;
    width: auto;
    font-size: 100%;
    vertical-align: top;
    bottom: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.right li {
    text-align: left;
}
```

Basically I just removed all of the `translate` properties from those divs removed the `margin-bottom` from the `ul`s and adding some `padding-bottom` to them. With the `max-height` removed from the `footer` tag the padding gives some space from the bottom of the page and expands the footer background so it doesn't leave a gap at the bottom.

Comment: I'm on mobile ATM but I can't wait to try this. Thank you for the effort!